# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException Chrome failed to Start displayed when other Chrome browser are open

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

"org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException Chrome failed to Start" message is displayed when the chrome browser launched (using default chrome profile) and **other chrome browsers are already open**

Full Error message

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed
> to start: exited normally.   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file
> doesn't exist)   (The process started from chrome location C:\Program
> Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so
> ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) Build info:
> version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:
> '2018-11-14T08:17:03'

This issue doesnt happens when there is no chrome browser opened when launching the new browser
Below is the code used

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
strUserProfile=System.getenv("USERPROFILE");
strUserProfile=strUserProfile+"\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data";
chromeOptions.addArguments("user-data-dir="+strUserProfile);
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Comment: @UndetectedSelenium: Can you please help